# Rect Color Unity

Tags: unity

So I'm drawing a rectangle, but I want to change it's Background color to red because at the moment it just has the background to blue. My code is as such:

```
drawArea = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
```

Comment: It looks like you've left out the drawing code here. Can you add that part?

Comment: There is no straight-forward way in Unity to "draw a rectangle". You usually have some kind of game object which looks like a rectangle on the screen. But there are many ways to achieve that. Which one did you choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rect is not a Drawable thing so you can't assign color to it. 
The Rect does not contain information for color, [Unity Docs ref](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.html).

This is something you're going to change when you are drawing that Rect. Let suppose you want to draw button out of it then you do something like this:

```
drawArea = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);

 //Changing Button Color to Red.
 GUI.backgroundColor = Color.red;
 GUI.Button( rect, "red button", guiStyle );

//Changing Button Color to Blue.
 GUI.backgroundColor = Color.blue;
 GUI.Button( rect, "blue button", guiStyle );
```

[The code is taken from Unity Answers.](https://answers.unity.com/questions/590543/c-setting-color-of-a-rect-on-creation.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: The [intermediate mode GUI system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html) is deprecated for several years now. It should not be used anymore in any new projects. Unity Technologies recommends to use it for debugging only.

Comment: @Philipp can you please share a link where it says "Deprecated" or something like it. as the link shared has no tag or anything to confirm if it is indeed deprecated. Also, have a look at this link I shared it's from unity 2019.3, Manuel.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.html

Comment: The link I posted in my last comment contains the following sections: "The IMGUI system is not generally intended to be used for normal in-game user interfaces that players might use and interact with". Further https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIToolkits.html says: "[IMGUI] is not the best option for building the UI of your game or application" and the table which helps people to choose the right UI technology for the purpose lists "not recommended" for IMGUI and "Runtime game UI".

Comment: @Philipp, Yes you are absolutely right about that and I know that but as the question goes it didn't mention any specific reason that why I am using it, or should I use it for reason X. This answer was very specific to the question. And I believe the answer has answered the question, Also I provided a link to the unity manual if one is interested he/she can read it.